# Сравнение символов в ассемблере линукс (gasm)

Tags: ассемблер, linux

Привествую. Пишу лабу, решил использовать gasm, информации по нему не так много в интернете, соотвественно, застопорился со сравнением символов. Суть программы - ввести строку, считать количество пробелов. К сожалению, работает только ввод и вывод, сравнение не работает (получается бесконечный цикл). Как правильно сравнивать определенный символ строки с символом?

```
//Удалить в предложении лишние пробелы.
//Количество пробелов не ограниченно.
//Подсчитать количество лишних пробелов
.section .bss
  .lcomm str,1024
.section .data
  hint:
    .string "Введите строку, техническое ограничение - 1024 символа (512 для UTF-8).\n"
  hint2:
    .string "Для изменения этого ограничения, обратитесь к программисту.\n"
  end:

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

  movl $4,%eax
  movl $1,%ebx
  movl $hint,%ecx
  length = end - hint
  movl $length,%edx
  int $0x80

  //Чтение строки
  movl $3,%eax
  movl $0,%ebx
  movl $str,%ecx
  movl $1024,%edx
  int $0x80

  movl $0,%eax #В %eax количество ЛИШНИХ пробелов
  movl $0,%ecx #Начинаем просмотр с нулевого элемента

loop_start:
  cmpl ' ',str(,%ecx,1)  #Сравниваем значения
  je sp
  incl %ecx
  jmp loop_start
sp:
  incl %eax
  cmpl $0x0A,str(,%ecx,1) #Проверка на символ перевода строки
  je loop_end
  incl %ecx
  jmp loop_start
loop_end:
  movl (%eax),%ecx  #Записываем результат в %ecx
  movl $4,%eax
  movl $1,%ebx
  movl $2,%edx
  int $0x80

 //Завершение программы
  movl $1,%eax
  movl $0,%ebx
  int $0x80
```

Comment: @rulevoi А что значит

     cmpl ' ',str(,%ecx,1)

Что с чем сравнивается? И как (сколько байт)?

Comment: @rulevoi, посмотрите (gcc -S mytest.c), как это делает компилятор, дальше сами...